# Xampp en varias redes

Tags: xampp, redes

Estoy usando xampp para hostear un proyecto personal, me explico:

**Info previa**

He montado un servidor web con una bdd (mysql) para mostrar las temperaturas y procesos usados por el pc.
 
Para las temperaturas uso un log creado por el programa speedfan.
Para los procesos he habilitado el protocolo snmp y los obtengo desde la web

**Explicación**

La cosa es que esto lo he hecho para poder cargar esa página web en una raspberry pi 3 b que tengo conectada directamente al pc (el pc tiene dos tarjetas de red, una va al router y otra a la rpi) de forma que si me quedo sin internet, la rpi puede seguir registrando y mostrando los datos.

La cosa es que de esta forma, solo puedo acceder a dicha web desde la rpi o desde el propio pc.

**PREGUNTA**

Hay alguna forma de que el xampp muestre está página web en ambas redes?
Red rpi-pc: 192.168.1.1
Red local: 192.168.0.x

Espero haberme explicado

Answer (score 0):

No sería mas fácil conectar la raspberry y el pc al router ?, los dos estarían en la misma red y te ahorrarías una tarjeta de red.

Todas las demás soluciones las veo mas complicadas, aquí te enumero algunas:

Tu pc tiene que "enrutar", a los clientes que se conecten les tienes que meter una ruta estática para que sepan llegar al pc y luego este sepa reenviarles a la RP.

Tu pc puede natear la ip de la RP por un puerto en concreto, ejemplo, la RP escucha por el 80, tu en el pc redireccionas todo lo que venga por el 90 a la ip del pc a la ip de la RP por el puerto 80.